# ts - timestamp input utility: setting time zone for time stamps

Tags: command-line, environment-variables, timestamp, time-zone

Under the **`ENVIRONMENT`** section `man` page for `ts` [ts(1)] reads:

> The standard TZ environment variable controls what time zone dates are
> assumed to be in, if a timezone is not specified as part of the date.

I understand that it uses whichever timezone is specified in the TZ environment variable. However, I do not understand how time zone can be specified as part of the date, my understanding is that `format` field in `ts [-r] [-i | -s] [format]` can be somehow used to specify the time zone.

The question is then, how can I specify the desired time zone for time stamps with `ts` utility without altering the environment variable?

Some background:

My server is located in a different time zone than me. As such whenever I use `ts` to add time stamps to the output, I want it to be displayed in my current time zone. I do not want to change `TZ` environment variable as it might interfere with currently running scripts or ones which will be run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### About `format`

The `format` string is not an iterface to choose a time zone. In my Debian `man 1 ts` states:

> The optional `format` parameter controls how the timestamp is formatted, as used by `strftime(3)`.

And `man 3 strftime` contains nothing that would make me think you can specify a time zone in the `format` string. It mentions the `TZ` environment variable. AFAIK the variable is *the* interface to choose a time zone.

`format` is a string where certain tokens get expanded, the rest stays literal. E.g. `%H` in `%H:%M:%S` expands to the hour, but `:` stays. In this model there is no room for a "config" string that would choose a time zone and *vanish*. In theory it could have been designed as integrated with tokens, so (e.g.) `%H(CEST)` would expand to the hour in the chosen time zone (here `CEST`). One way or another this would be a poor solution. We want to write code (including the `format` string) that works in any time zone, we want to be able to specify a time zone at run time. The `TZ` environment variable is the way, a neat design.

---

#### Using `TZ` "locally"

A general syntax in a POSIX-like shell to specify an environment variable exclusively for one command is:

```
var=value executable …
```

This will put `var` in the environment of the running `executable`, without altering the environment of the shell.

Note if a process (like `executable`) spawns a child process then the child will inherit the variable, unless the parent is designed to prevents this. `ts` does not create children though.

Example usage with `ts`:

```
date '+%H:%M:%S %z' | TZ=UTC-8 ts '<%H:%M:%S %z>'
```

or even:

```
TZ=UTC+3 date '+%H:%M:%S %z' | TZ=UTC-8 ts '<%H:%M:%S %z>'
```

(The latter shows that you can specify `TZ` separately for each process in a pipe.)

Notes:

- [Why does `TZ=UTC-8` produce dates that are `UTC+8`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/104088/108618)
- In an interactive shell an alias like `alias ts='TZ=UTC-8 ts'` may be useful. (Keep in mind if you now try to run `TZ=UTC-5 ts` then the alias will change it to `TZ=UTC-5 TZ=UTC-8 ts` and the value from the alias will win.)
- If `ts` is run from a script then:

  - You can specify `TZ` for the entire script (`TZ=… ./the_script`); probably you don't want this because in general other parts of the script will be affected.
  - Or you need to *modify* the script and turn `ts` into `TZ=… ts`. Your idea of changing the format string would require a similar modification, so I guess it's not a problem for you.
  - Or you can use a wrapper. See below.

---

#### Wrapper

In case you want to impact `ts` in scripts *without* modifying the scripts, you can create a wrapper that will be called instead of the real `ts`. This is an example wrapper script:

```sh
#/bin/sh
if [ -n "$TS_TZ" ]; then
   TZ="$TS_TZ"
   export TZ
fi
exec /usr/bin/ts "$@"
```

Notes:

- The above code uses `/usr/bin/ts` as the real `ts`; adjust this path if needed.
- If you want to test the wrapper in an interactive shell and you have just tested the alias mentioned above, don't forget to `unalias ts`.

Name the script `ts`, make it executable (`chmod +x ts`) and move it to a directory that occurs before `/usr/bin` in your `PATH` (you may need to create such directory and expand your `PATH` accordingly; I use `$HOME/bin`).

From now on a non-empty value of `TS_TZ` environment variable will overwrite `TZ` for `ts`. This means you can do:

```
TS_TZ=UTC-8
export TS_TZ
```

and for you `ts` will automatically use `TZ=UTC-8`. This will happen even in a newly started script, if only `ts` in the script is resolved according to your `PATH`.

If `TS_TZ` is unset or empty then the wrapper will exec to the real `ts` without any trick, as if the wrapper wasn't there. In other words the wrapper is transparent unless `TS_TZ` is in the environment and it's not empty.

---

#### But wait!

But wait. `man 1 ts` contains the following statement:

> The standard `TZ` environment variable controls what time zone dates are assumed to be in, if a timezone is not specified as part of the date.

Doesn't this imply a time zone may or may not be specified as part of the date? Where can it be specified, if not in `format`?

Well, it looks this applies to dates provided as *input* when you use `-r`.

> If the `-r` switch is passed, it instead converts existing timestamps in the input to relative times […]. If both `-r` and a `format` is passed, the existing timestamps are converted to the specified format.

You can do this:

```
echo 'Aug 20 23:59:59 whatever' | TZ=UTC-8 ts -r '%H:%M:%S %z'
```

and the statement means `Aug 20 23:59:59` will be interpreted as if it was also in `TZ=UTC-8`.

<sup>Side note: the manual says that "many common timestamp formats are supported" (as input), but I failed to find a format that includes information about the time zone and is supported.</sup>

Comment: Thank you, this technically resolves the issue. However, is there a way to specify the time zone using `format` string, rather than temporary setting the environment variable for `ts`? Or the quote `if a timezone is not specified as part of the date` from `ts` `man` page means something other than specifying time zone in the `[format]` string?

Comment: @mikeskk See the expanded answer.